# Looping through variables with an iterative component

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to loop through several data frames that all have a standard name other than the last character which is an integer. I am trying to loop through the data frames and perform a task on each but I don't know how to reference each data frame by name.

```
for(i in 1:length(xyz)){
    approx(df & i & $X, df & i & $Y, xout=aim)
}
```

that is essentially the format I want where each iteration will increase the number i and therefore the name of the data frame eg. df1$X, df2$X, df3$X, df4$X...

I know this code won't work but I don't know what will

Comment: put them in a list and apply (`lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df[0-9]+')); lapply(lst1, function(i) approx(i$X, ...))`)

Comment: A rather hacky version to get your own loop to work would be `approx(eval(parse(text = paste0("df", i, "$X"))), eval(parse(text = paste0("df", i, "$Y"))), xout = aim)`. But listen to @Sotos and use a list.

Comment: I don't entirely understand the method being used here by @Sotos how is the function being applied here?

Comment: I understand the method using by @Leo using functions to concatenate the variable names but I don't understand how that list method would contain the information and how the approximation function would be applied

Comment: @tombat7112: The `mget(ls(...))` will put all your data.frames in a list called `lst1`. Afterwards you apply the function `function(i) approx(i$X, i$Y, xout = aim)` over the list of your data.frames with the `lapply()` call and either print the output, or save it to another list by assigning `output <- lapply(...)`.

Comment: By the way, the use of `mget()` is very elegant, as `mget` specifies `Search by name for zero or more objects`, so with @Sotos pattern, it'll collect all your data.frames without you having to specify the range. I like it, and I think your should post it as an answer, @Sotos.

Answer (score 0):

The way I 'd do it, is to put them in a list and iterate. Using `mget` we fetch the objects of interest by specifying a pattern in `ls()` which in your case would be `df[0-9]+`. Finally use `lapply` to iterate.

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df[0-9]+'))
lapply(lst1, function(i) approx(i$X, i$Y, xout = aim))
```